# Definition of a compact : something I don't get

Tags: general-topology, definition

In my book they define the compact as follows :

$G$ is compact if for every covering of $G$ by open, we can pick out a finite number of the sets that still covers G.

But a union of open is an open.

Thus, if G is compact, there is a finite union of open that covers G.
Thus G is open.

But in $\mathbb{R}^n$ compact => closed so I don't get.

PS : I am beginner in topology so I would like a simple explanation using definitions =) (and not a magic theorem that I don't know for example).

Comment: $\{(-2,1),(0,2)\}$ is an open cover of $[-1,1].$ That doesn't mean $[0,1]=(-2,1)\cup (0,2).$ Thus we can't conclude that $[0,1]$ is open.

Comment: The finite subcover is just that, a *covering.* That means that the union of the subcover elements *contains* the set, not that it is *equal* to the set.

Comment: @DavidBowman Ah ok ! It makes sense now, thanks :) !

Comment: Alternatively, if you know about the subspace topology, we can think of it as equalling the union of things that are open in the subspace topology.

Comment: Also, if $G$ is the entire topological space in question (not just a subset of a larger space), then $G$ will be __both__ open and closed automatically. So an open covering shows the space is open in this case, but we already knew that in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like this was cleared up in the comments while I was writing my answer, but here it is anyways (it might still be useful to OP on account of the precise definitions given below).

> **Definition**: An open cover of a set $G$ is a family $\{G_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in \mathcal{A}}$ such that $G \subset \cup_{\alpha \in \mathcal{A}} G_\alpha$.
>
> **Definition**: A set $G$ is compact if for every open cover $\mathcal{G} = \{G_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in \mathcal{A}}$ of $G$, there exists a finite subset $\{G_{\alpha_n}\}_{n=1}^N$ of $\mathcal{G}$ that is also an open cover of $G$.

Note, in particular, that a set $G$ being compact does not imply that there *exists* a finite open cover $\{G_{n}\}_{n=1}^N$ of $G$ whose union is exactly equal to $G$ (i.e., $\cup_n G_n = G$). This is the source of confusion.

Comment: Of course there is a finite open cover of $G$: one is $\{ X \}$ (where $X$ is the whole space).

Comment: You are right. Note "whose union is exactly equal to $G$".

Comment: Ah, yes, I seem to have skimmed over that (in my defense it is on the next line on my screen...)

Comment: @Ian: actually, it's probably because the first version of my answer didn't have that line. I noticed very quickly my erroneous statement and updated, but you might have seen the old version.